# Pandas add columns and index dynamically and update existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a dataframe, save it and update it dynamically. `timestamp` is supposed to be the index. I will get `price` and `qty` as column values every minute of the timestamp in a dict. Each time the `price` would change. If it changes, I have to update the old `qty` value.

The end result of the dataframe is as follows:

```
timestamp                100     200     300
2020-11-01 12:00:00       4       3       5
```

The the next minute I will have data in a list of dict like

```
[{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 200, 'qty': 6},
{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 400, 'qty': 3},
{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 500, 'qty': 1}]
```

The dataframe should update like so:

```
timestamp                100     200     300    400    500
2020-11-01 12:00:00       4       3       5      0      0
2020-11-01 12:01:00       4       9       5      3      1
```

```
[{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:02:00', 'price': 200, 'qty': 6},
{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:02:00', 'price': 300, 'qty': -1},
{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:02:00', 'price': 500, 'qty': 1}]
```

The dataframe should update like so:

```
timestamp                100     200     300    400    500
2020-11-01 12:00:00       4       3       5      0      0
2020-11-01 12:01:00       4       9       5      3      1
2020-11-01 12:02:00       4       15      0      3      2
```

so basically creating a historical change as well as adding new columns on the fly if new prices are added to the existing dataframe. I will store the dataframe in csv every minute and read and update the new values.

New values coming in the dict in above example; at price 200, the qty is sum of the previous and new value. in addition, if qty is -1, the value should be updated to 0.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have put a small framework of your requirement. Apply if it works,

```
# Create two functions for creating and updating the data frames

def create_df():
        return pd.DataFrame([[Dict_val[0]["timestamp"]]+[val["qty"] if val["qty"] !=-1 else 0 for val in Dict_val]],columns=[["timestamp"]+[val["price"] for val in Dict_val]])


def update_df(old_df):
    df=(pd.concat([old_df,create_df()]).fillna(0,downcast='infer'))
  df.iloc[-1,1:] += df.iloc[-2,1:]
  return df
# Initial value to load in dataframe
Dict_val = [{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:00:00', 'price': 100, 'qty': 4},
                {'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:00:00', 'price': 200, 'qty': 3},
                {'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:00:00', 'price': 300, 'qty': 5}]

# Create a Initial DataFrame with the timestamp

df_1 = create_df()

print(df_1)

    timestamp            100    200  300
0   2020-11-01 12:00:00  4      3    5

# Now assuming you have the updated Dict_val for the next minute

Dict_val = [{'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 200, 'qty': 6},
                {'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 400, 'qty': 3},
                {'timestamp': '2020-11-01 12:01:00', 'price': 500, 'qty': 1}]

# The below steps will be repeated every minute

# Update the dataframe with new values and save in save name

df_1 = update_df(df_1) # this line to be repeated at every minute with new Dict values


print(df_1)

    timestamp           100 200 300 400 500
0   2020-11-01 12:00:00 4   3   5   0   0
0   2020-11-01 12:01:00 4   6   5   3   1

# Next minute run again the previous step
```

Comment: This partially works although on the update_df I want it to sum the old and new value so for price: 200 the sum is 9.also if the qty returned is - 1, have to set the value there as 0.

Comment: This works for the sum, but if in the next val I set the value of 200 as -1, it still returned  9

Comment: Additionally, it seems if the same timestamp is added, duplicate rows are being created.